# Git hooks doesn't work on Source Tree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, githooks

Via Terminal everything works correctly but in Source Tree doesn't work

This is my `pre-commit` hook

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# hook script for swiftlint. It will triggered when you make a commit.
#
# If you want to use, type commands in your console.
# $ ln -s ../../pre-commit-swiftlint.sh .git/hooks/pre-commit
# $ chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-commit

LINT=$(which swiftlint)

if [[ -e "${LINT}" ]]; then
   echo "SwiftLint Start..."
else
echo "SwiftLint does not exist, download from https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint"
exit 1
fi

RESULT=$($LINT lint --quiet)

if [ "$RESULT" == '' ]; then
printf "\e[32mSwiftLint Finished.\e[39m\n"
else
echo ""
printf "\e[41mSwiftLint Failed.\e[49m Please check below:\n"

while read -r line; do

    FILEPATH=$(echo $line | cut -d : -f 1)
    L=$(echo $line | cut -d : -f 2)
    C=$(echo $line | cut -d : -f 3)
    TYPE=$(echo $line | cut -d : -f 4 | cut -c 2-)
    MESSAGE=$(echo $line | cut -d : -f 5 | cut -c 2-)
    DESCRIPTION=$(echo $line | cut -d : -f 6 | cut -c 2-)
    if [ "$TYPE" == 'error' ]; then
        printf "\n  \e[31m$TYPE\e[39m\n"
    else
        printf "\n  \e[33m$TYPE\e[39m\n"
    fi
    printf "    \e[90m$FILEPATH:$L:$C\e[39m\n"
    printf "    $MESSAGE - $DESCRIPTION\n"
done <<< "$RESULT"

printf "\nCOMMIT ABORTED. Please fix them before commiting.\n"

exit 1
fi
```

Comment: What does not work? Is not executed? Or is it executed with an error message?

Comment: Fixed by this [issue](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/SourceTree-Hook-failing-because-paths-don-t-seem-to-be-set/qaq-p/274792)

Comment: by adding ```export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH```

Comment: Great! Add this as an answer: you can accept your own answer. That will help others.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fixed by adding `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

Source Tree [issue](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/SourceTree-Hook-failing-because-paths-don-t-seem-to-be-set/qaq-p/274792)

Comment: I added this string directly into pre-commit file at the top of the file

Answer (score 19):

For me I had to open Sourcetree through command line

```
open /Applications/Sourcetree.app
```

from here ([SourceTree-Hook-failing-because-paths-don-t-seem-to-be-set](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/SourceTree-Hook-failing-because-paths-don-t-seem-to-be-set/qaq-p/274792))

Comment: So everytime I have to open SourceTree with the terminal and not directly through system?

Comment: @ShoebMirza This is what worked for me. Maybe there is a better way. I got used to quite quickly.

Comment: It is working for me only if I open SourceTree with terminal and not directly through system

Comment: You can also install the SourceTree command-line tools (it's available as a menu option within the SourceTree app) then run `stree` from the command line. (See [this comment](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/SourceTree-Hook-failing-because-paths-don-t-seem-to-be-set/qaq-p/274792).)

Comment: funny, works, but how does this fix the issue?

Comment: This does not work in sourcetree v4.1.3. They seem to have added some common paths like /usr/local/bin to the environment, but not the exact $PATH value in terminal. In my case, `/Users/<username>/go/bin` path is needed but sourcetree does not find it. My workaround is to symlink the binaries, `ln -s /Users/<username>/go/bin/<binary> /usr/local/bin/<binary>`.

Answer (score 5):

Solution of 2022 year if you are using `nvm` and `husky@>=5` on MacOS:

Just run this command in Terminal:

```bash
echo 'export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"\n[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"' > ~/.huskyrc
```

Please rate the solution if it works for you to move it up.

Comment: Can you explain what that does, and why it fixes the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Fixed by executing git config --global core.hooksPath '~/.githooks'  command

I had set core.hooksPath to wrong directory.
Reseting it with git config --global core.hooksPath '~/.githooks'

Answer (score 2):

Either add `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` in `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zshrc`

OR

Simply go to Sourcetree preferences and instead of embedded git, use system git under git settings.

Answer (score 1):

This works on OSX, update ~/.bash_profile with

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

Install Command Line Tools, and you can now call the following from a terminal:

stree

to open Sourcetree through command line.

Git Hooks will now in Sourcetree if it works in your Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

In my case exporting the path did not work. I had to reinstall husky and restart sourcetree. Then it was all working again.